# Truncate string in Rails: "..." showing up on strings at length

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, string, truncate

I'm currently trying to truncate any strings greater than 65 characters.

My code is

```
<title><%= truncate(title.html_safe, length:65) %></title>
```

It works great for titles longer than 65 characters. But titles that are exactly 65 character still get truncated.

For example:

> title:"This post is exactly 65 characters characters characters
>   characte"
>
> shows on page as "This post is exactly 65 characters characters
>   characters chara..."

Should I not be using truncate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`truncate` is the right method. This might be a bug in your version of rails? Here's what I get on my console:

```
[5] pry(main)> helper.truncate("This post is exactly 56 characters characters characters characte", length: 65)
=> "This post is exactly 56 characters characters characters characte"
[6] pry(main)> helper.truncate("This post is exactly 56 characters characters characters characte", length: 64)
=> "This post is exactly 56 characters characters characters char..."
```

I'm running Rails 4.0.4 in this example.

Comment: That's weird. Thanks everyone for the quick response - I'll check my version.

Answer (score 5):

> If you are using `rails 4.2` or above then you can use
>   `truncate_words` method.

```
<title><%= (title.html_safe).truncate_words(5) %></title>
```

Comment: this truncates for number of words, not chars

Answer (score 2):

> title = "This post is exactly 56 characters characters characters characte".length
>    => 65

`<title><%= truncate(title.html_safe, length:56) %></title>` # will be truncated

`<title><%= truncate(title.html_safe, length:65) %></title>` # this should work fine, I just tried.

**Rails 3.2.17**

Answer (score 1):

the truncate method work just as expected. Please output the length after your invocation of title.html_safe, is it possible that your string contains some trailing spaces?

Answer (score 1):

We call it **`Ellipsis`**. Just to add to the above answers you can achieve *ellipsis by **css, jquery and rails.***

[**`css:`**](http://html5hub.com/ellipse-my-text/#i.9e1nqynchcrrsi)

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**`Jquery:`**

There is a really good [`jquery plugin dotdotdot`](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/). I have used it one of my projects and it works like a charm. It uses height and width of your parent element smartly to show ellipsis.

**`Rails:`**

Rails has a text helper [truncate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) which can be used like:

```
<%= truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away", length: 65) %>
```

CSS is obviously the quickest way to achieve ellipsis but it has its disadvantages that it **doesn't provide a way to limit your characters and it's tricky to get it to work for multiple lines**.

Jquery plugin dotdotdot **works great for multiple lines** but i don't think it has option to specify character limit either.

Rails truncate it obviously **server side** and will allow you an option to specify character limit.